# Facebook/Twitter Share link: Only Image or Youtube video from Post content

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, twitter, share

I have a Gutenberg Post Content to Slick Slider with YT videos and images in the Slider. The goal is to share ONLY a YT video or an Image that is attached in each post Slide.
 I have worked around and ended with two shared links: for YT videos and Images. They work fine, but as you can figure it out... there are 2 shared links...

Facebook Share Links: Youtube video / Images

```
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fyoutube.com/watch\?v=<?php echo my_wrap( $match[2] ); ?>" target="_blank">Facebook</a>

 <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); echo esc_url( $image[0] ); ?>" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

Twitter Share Link: Youtube video / Images

```
 <a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?&text=Check+this+video&amp;url=http%3A//www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3D<?php echo my_wrap( $match[2] ); ?>" target="_blank">Twitter</a>

 <a href="http://www.twitter.com/share?&text=Check+this+image&amp;url=<?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); echo esc_url( $image[0] ); ?>" target="_blank">Twitter</a>
```

How can I get a single shared link?.
 Is there any option to share only a YT video or an Image that is attached in each Slide?

Demo site: [mouse over on Like button](https://koreanwave.org)

Please let me know if you need me to clarify anything else and thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: You can't combine them. Facebook only allow you to share URLs. Then Facebook get information from that URL. If you want to share a Youtube URL Facebook goes to Youtube and get information about that URL.

Comment: Thank you  @WizKid . You meant that do I need to show 2 Facebook share links: one for videos and another for images? here is what I have [demo share link](https://koreanwave.cloudaccess.host)

Comment: It is pretty unclear, what you actually want here. What do you mean, when you say “detect”? Are you talking about the code on your end, is that supposed to figure out whether a post _has_ a YT video attached to it, or … what?

Comment: @CBroe content is updated, Thank you!